# multithreading code with rendevous objects time delay while running the code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading

first of all thanks in advance for any help. I really appreciate it.
I am running some Python multi-threading code, where every thread is streaming the results of a Rendevous Object which basically works totally fine. But now I fugured out, that with some runtime, the results get delayed as if my computer is not able to process all threads near term. I am wondering if it is possible to speed up the process by using multi-threading in combination with multi-processing? I am not quite sure if this is a) even possible and b) solving my problem. Or would I need "just" more CPU power in terms of GHz?

Thanks for your help and best regards!

Comment: It would help if you could insert some minimal example code into your question showing the described  behavior. Maybe you can strip down your code to just starting the processes doing some random stuff.

Comment: Thanks for you rely @bjhend. Please find below my answer.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply @bjhend. Please find more information below.

Basically I create gPRC based threads in which `_MultiThreadedRendezvous` objects are getting streamed within a `for` loop. The result/feedback of evey thread will be stored in a own pandas dataframe which is not going to be saved on the disk.
I do use the general threading module and not the concurrent futures module (if that makes already a difference?). At least I decided to go with multi-threading instead of multi processing because I believe that I have I/O bound processes. In total I am starting round about ~2000 threads in that way.

As the one of the feedback data of the `_MultiThreadedRendezvous` objects is containing the time, I figured out that with some runtime, the results are getting "delayed" (like I mentioned above). Anyway as I do imagine the overall process like a "worker/costumer procedure" with which the `Queue` module/function is decribed (first come, first serve; each queue is like an order etc.), I feel like that the CPU clockrate is my most concern. On the other hand if I would imagine running the code on 28-core machine instead of a 4-core cpu I think it should perform faster (just a feeling.. again, rationally I think a the clockrate in combination with the possible threads would increase the process way better).

Hopefully those information will help you. Thanks again!

Comment: Sorry, this is not an answer to your SO-question. Please edit your question and insert your new text there and delete this answer. SO is not meant to be a discussion forum, instead it is a user-contributed knowledge base of specific programming questions and their verifiable concrete answers. My comment was a review comment as a more SO-experienced user to help you improve your question.